# Aggregate Willmott and Matsuura Temperature Climate Data on Country Level

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, aggregation, climate

I'm looking for monthly mean temperature data on the country-level since 1900, or at least 1950, with temperature weighted according to population density.

The common database for the spatial temperature is by [Willmott & Matsuura](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/download.html#T2017)

The population data typically comes from [Gridded Population of the World](https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-density-rev11/data-download)

I downloaded the Willmott & Matsuura temperature data, which is a single gz-file. 
How can I aggregate the Willmott-Matssura temperature data at the country-level using R?

Is there an open code for this? Or has someone else maybe done it
(as it is a commonly used dataset in the literature)?

Comment: I don't know if there is a standard open code for this - I guess not. But I have done this kind of aggregation work in the past in R using the `overlay` in the raster package. You basically overlay you country-polygons on top of the raster - which is the standard format in which you load the climate data - and calculate your summary statistic of choice. Not too hard, can take some time to aggregate depending on computer power. Rather than W&M I would recommend Berkeley Earth though http://berkeleyearth.org/data/ (but that's very subjective).

Comment: Please read our FAQ on asking a well structured question. It is also customary to show what you have tried thus far and not just ask "do it for me". I would highly recommend search this site as, this type of question has been asked many times already. You can use `[R]` to make search results specific to R.

Comment: The README for exactextract (https://github.com/isciences/exactextract) shows how to compute a population-weighted mean temperature by country with a single command-line call.